# how to remove the .aspx .asmx suffix in asp.net

Tags: asp.net

Most of our application are based on asp.net.

So all of the url will have the suffix like .aspx or .asmx

I wonder if there is any idea to remove them?

Comment: Use url rewriting or in advance use Url Routing

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Have a look at one of the following tutorials:

**URL Routing** (ASP.Net 4.0 and higher):

- [**URL Routing with ASP.NET 4 Web Forms**](http://weblogs.asp.net/scottgu/archive/2009/10/13/url-routing-with-asp-net-4-web-forms-vs-2010-and-net-4-0-series.aspx) -- *Scott Guthrie*

**URL Rewriting** (ASP.Net 3.5 and lower):

- [**Url Rewriting with ASP.NET**](http://weblogs.asp.net/scottgu/archive/2007/02/26/tip-trick-url-rewriting-with-asp-net.aspx) -- *Scott Guthrie*
- [**Clean URL Structure in ASP.Net**](http://sharpertutorials.com/clean-url-structure-in-aspnet/) -- *Sharpertutorials.com*

Comment: This depends on the specific implementation, but it could theoretically work with .asmx files as well. I haven't tried it myself though.