# How do i remove the '.aspx' extension from url

Tags: c#, asp.net

How do i remove extensions from page URL in c#.

e.g: `questions/ask.aspx`

I want the url of my web application in following format:

```
questions/ask
```

If any one have a idea then pleas guide me...

Comment: This is a duplicate question: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13439561/how-to-remove-the-aspx-asmx-suffix-in-asp-net

Answer (score 4):

If you are using web forms you need to add a custom router handler using [URL Routing](http://weblogs.asp.net/scottgu/url-routing-with-asp-net-4-web-forms-vs-2010-and-net-4-0-series) in the `Global.asax` file.
Check out this sample:

**Global.asax**

```
public class Global : System.Web.HttpApplication
{

    //Register your routes, match a custom URL with an .aspx file. 
    private void RegisterRoutes(RouteCollection routes)
    {
        routes.MapPageRoute("About", "about", "~/about.aspx");
        routes.MapPageRoute("Index", "index", "~/index.aspx");
    }

    //Init your new route table inside the App_Start event.
    protected void Application_Start(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        this.RegisterRoutes(RouteTable.Routes);
    } 
}
```

Answer (score 2):

You have to Implement `URL Rewriting`

> URL rewriting is the process of intercepting an incoming Web request
>   and redirecting the request to a different resource. When performing
>   URL rewriting, typically the URL being requested is checked and, based
>   on its value, the request is redirected to a different URL

You can Add this in `Web.Config`

```
<urlMappings enabled="true">
 <add url="~/questions/ask" mappedUrl="~/questions/ask.aspx?page=Ask"/>
</urlMappings>
```

[**See Here**](http://www.aspnettutorials.com/tutorials/webservices/learn-url-rewriting-with-asp-net-4-0-and-c/)