# Page not found without an extension aspx

Tags: c#, asp.net

i got stuck with this problem

in debug mode, there is no problem at all for asp routing HTTP://localhost:50323/Login
but when I publish in live server return error page not found but when I add aspx extension login.aspx page appears correctly

another system in the live server got no problem with asp routing.
just this time I reused the existing code and add some enhancement code and try to publish as the new system got this error page not found but in debug, mode got no problem for this issue.

Does anyone know how to fix it?
I am using framework 4.6.2

Comment: A service has to be running that accepts port number 50323.

Comment: but in live server lets say my domain is google.com when I run on browser HTTP://google.com/login the server return error page not found but if I up HTTP://google.com/login.aspx the page appear correctly. its look like asp routing not trigger in live server in debug mode using visual studio IIS Express there is no problem at all

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How do i remove the '.aspx' extension from url](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27792467/how-do-i-remove-the-aspx-extension-from-url)

Comment: i already have the code 

        protected void Application_Start(object sender, EventArgs e)
        { 
            RouteConfig.RegisterRoutes(RouteTable.Routes);
            BundleConfig.RegisterBundles(BundleTable.Bundles);
        }
but it looks like the code not trigger in live server

Comment: You can use fromcmd.exe >Netstat -a to see if anybody is listening.  Then you can check the role : https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/web-forms/overview/older-versions-security/roles/creating-and-managing-roles-cs

Comment: Could be the default page?  You go to .../login but the server is looking for ../login/default.aspx or ../login/index.apsx ?